# A doubt regarding the deformation retraction of $X$ to its point of intersection.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher's Algebraic Topology says the following on pg. 2

> Not all deformation retractions arise in this way from mapping cylinders, however. For example, the thick $\mathbf{X}$ deformation retracts to the thin $X$, which in terms retracts to the point of intersection of its two crossbars. The net result is a deformation retraction of $\mathbf{X}$ onto a point, during which certain pairs of points follow paths that merge before reaching their final destination.

I don't understand this. Why can't the two cross bars retract to the point of intersection without any two paths crossing?

Answer (score 1):

Hatcher is stating a property that this *particular* retraction mapping has; he is not stating a property that *all* retraction mappings would have. He is simply describing how it 'works' in this instance, what it looks like.

Comment: I am talking about _this_ instance too. The way I can visualize it, each point on $X$ would deform to a single point without any two paths crossing.

Comment: You can certainly do it that way. There is not a problem with that. In Hatcher's example he's simply doing it another way, where the thick $\mathbf{X}$ first retracts onto the thin $X$. There's no conflict, because it's just one example of a retraction.